# in Material UI Icon doesn't work as expected

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI. In the doc it shows that I can use:

```
 import Icon from "@material-ui/core/Icon";
   ...
  <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.button}>
     blabla
      <Icon className={classes.rightIcon}>send</Icon>
  </Button>
```

but what it shows is a button with a text "BLABLA SE" which is wrong.

But when I use:

```
import SendIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Send";
....
    <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.button}>
     Blabla
     <SendIcon className={classes.rightIcon} />
    </Button>
```

It works just fine, with a text `BLABLA` and a send icon on the left side of it.

In the sandBox provided in the doc both work. So why the first case doesn't
work for me?

Comment: Do you have the same version of the library in your environment as the sandbox has?

Comment: @Tholle i have 3.3.2 which is the latest and in the sandbox it says : ` "@material-ui/core": "latest"`

Answer (score 6):

I think there is an error in this documentation example : https://material-ui.com/demos/buttons/#buttons-with-icons-and-label

```
import Icon from '@material-ui/core/Icon';
```

shoud be

```
import SendIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Send';
```

Here is a **working version** with this replacement : https://codesandbox.io/s/k3rjyoq32v

---

The module imported with this path `@material-ui/core/Icon` is not an svg icon itself, it is the Icon component documented here : https://material-ui.com/api/icon/

There are basically **three ways of working with Icons in material-ui** :

1. `@material-ui/core/Icon` : Component useful for displaying font icons. See https://material-ui.com/style/icons/#font-icons
2. `@material-ui/icons` : package with a set of [Material Icons](https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline) converted to SVG icons usable as React components. See https://material-ui.com/style/icons/#svg-material-icons
3. `@material-ui/core/SvgIcon` : Component to use any SVG as an icon. See https://material-ui.com/style/icons/#svg-icons

Comment: thanks, but my question is why the exact code that works on the sandbox doesn't work in my project?

Comment: Could you provide a link to the sandbox you refer to please ?

Comment: here you are, https://codesandbox.io/s/mzlo9lnqp9   the part that I'm talking about is that `Send` button

Comment: This sandbox does not work on my side. I can not see the Send Icon. And here you are too ;-) https://codesandbox.io/s/k3rjyoq32v working version with the modification explained in my answer. (Do not use Icon component and import Send material icon instead)

Answer (score 4):

I think you've solved your own problem since I've seen you have got the icon to show in your codesandbox.

Had the same problem and found out that I didn't import the material icons font family in the ***index.html***.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
```

Only with the above import will the  component work.

Comment: Same issue, and it says in the [docs](https://material-ui.com/components/icons/#font-icons) that this is required